# How to use function of a PHP-extension in a controller of Symfony

Tags: php, namespaces, pecl, symfony

Im new to Symfony 3.0 and my current project deals with wordanalysis. more precisely with counting of syllables of a word. It was hard to find a solution for this need. After a while i stumble upon the PECL package "ps" ( http://php.net/manual/de/ref.ps.php ), to be exact the function ps_hyphenate() ( http://php.net/manual/de/function.ps-hyphenate.php ). I successfully installed this package and its dependencies (pslib and inittool) and managed it to get the example of ps_hyphenate() work on my local environment.

Inspired by my lucky streak i tried to implement a method in my symfony controller

```
private function countSyllables($string) {
    $psdoc = ps_new();
    ps_set_parameter($psdoc, "hyphendict", "/../Utils/hyph_de.dic");
    $hyphens = ps_hyphenate($psdoc, $string);
    ps_delete($psdoc);
    return count($hyphens);
}
```

As a result i get this errormessage:

```
Attempted to call function "ps_new" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller".
```

"No problem" i thought. Just escape the specific namespace of the controller.

```
...
    $psdoc = \ps_new();
    ...
```

this was the result:

```
 Attempted to call function "ps_new" from the global namespace.
```

Whats wrong? Aren't PECL Extensions part of the global namespace? How can i make this livesaving function work?

Love Fab.

Comment: Is the extension properly enabled (i.e. can you use these functions in a simple PHP script without Symfony)?

Comment: Hi, yes i tried to run the example of http://php.net/manual/de/function.ps-hyphenate.php on my local environment and succeed. Is there any possibility that symfony uses a different php.ini?

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much for your hint!

Comment: How did you actually solve your issue?

Comment: Please add your findings as an answer and accept instead of editing the original answer. This way other users will see directly that and how the issue was resolved :)

Comment: Sorry. This was my first question. For now on i will promise to improve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved!

I have two different php installations. Both have different php.ini's. I think i just run one of these installations, but symfony uses the old php.ini. So my solution was to add the following to the correct php.ini

```
extension_dir = "/usr/local/php5/extensions/"
extension=ps.so
```

Note to myself: next time also try to Googwle for "syllable php". I found a much proper textanalysis package:

https://github.com/DaveChild/Text-Statistics

This mighty bundle returns the amount of syllables of a word you give in.

You can easily include it to your symfony project with the composer

```
$ composer require davechild/text-statistics
```

Love Fab